# as3 show loader while saving image to gallery

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

Am making an android app using AIR for Android and as3. Following is my code to save image into device gallery. The image gets saved but I want to show a loader while the image is getting saved. This code does not work approprietely. Please point out if I am making any mistake here.

```
    mysaveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ftnSave);

    function ftnSave():void
    {
    mysaveBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ftnSave);
    mysaveBtn.visible = false;
    var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1080, 1920); 
    jpgSource.draw(myTheme); 
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100); 
    var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource); 
    var fs : FileStream = new FileStream(); 
    var targetFile : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg'); 
    fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE); 
    fs.writeBytes(imgByteData); 
    fs.close(); 
    if( CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData ){
    new CameraRoll().addBitmapData(jpgSource);
    mysaveBtn.visible = true;
    mysaveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ftnSave);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class "[Asynchronous Image Encoders](https://github.com/LeeBurrows/Async-Image-Encoders)"

This class can also save large images to prevent freezing your application .